# Please help fix ValueError: ... is not in the list python

Tags: python, list, indexing, naming

I have the code below:

```
def negative_nbr(x):
    ls = []
    for i in x:
        if i < 0:
            ls += [ls.index(i)]
    return ls
y = [1,-5, 3, -4, 3]
negative_nbr(y)
```

and it's result:

```
>>>
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_1452\3255678202.py in <module>
      1 y = [1,-5, 3, -4, 3]
----> 2 negative_nbr(y)

~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_1452\3262551839.py in negative_nbr(x)
      3     for i in x:
      4         if i < 0:
----> 5             ls += [ls.index(i)]
      6     return ls

ValueError: -5 is not in list
```

Please help resolve it
Thank you very much

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hzXvr.png) help

Comment: What are you trying to do? Obviosuly -5 is not in `ls`. What do you expect to happen?

Comment: That's what the `index` method does. You need to catch the exception and decide what to do if `ls.index(i)` fails.

Comment: You are attempting to reference a list by index using the value of a list item. Conceptually that is fine, but you would need to be rather careful about the values you used. In this case there is of course no index -5. Note that list slice notation does support negative indexing if that helps.

Comment: thank you guys. The syntax of ls.index must be x.index